# The differences between orators and declaimers

Tags: word-difference, spoken-english

What are the differences between the orators and declaimers? I am confused in these two. What is exactly the complete explanation?

Comment: Just a reminder as you are a seasoned member here:  http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please

Answer (score 4):

A **[declaimer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/declaimer)** speaks in a somewhat artificial, loud and exaggerated style - like on a theater stage, where an actor recites the lines supplied by the author. The term focusses on the *style of speech* over the content.

An **[orator](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orator)** simply gives a speech. Typically we would expect the orator to be also the author of the speech or at least deliver it as if it was their own opinion.

A good orator captures their audience with arguments and a pleasing presentation, a declaimer has their rightful home declaiming Shakespeare on the theater stage, in a social context, the attitude is often less welcome.

Answer (score 2):

"Orator" is generally a positive description -- if you call someone an *orator*, it means that person is good at making speeches.

> **Orator** (noun): [A public speaker, especially one who is eloquent or skilled.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/orator)

"Declaimer" is [not often used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=orator%2Cdeclaimer&year_start=1990&year_end=2020&corpus=15&smoothing=3).  Usually you will see the verb "to declaim" or the adjective "declamatory", but not the noun form.

> **To declaim** (verb): [Utter or deliver words in a rhetorical or impassioned way, as if to an audience](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/declaim)

A "declaimer" is someone who *declaims*, meaning a public speaker who delivers speeches in an exaggerated manner to heighten the emotional or rhetorical impact.  It is neither negative nor positive.

An orator can be a declaimer, and vice-versa.